# Configure my app to send emails using postfix relay

Tags: python, email, google-cloud-platform, smtp, relay

Currently we have a postfix relay Linux server hosted on GCP and it is connected to proofpoint.

My Python application is on another vm. I am wondering how can I setup my app to send out email using the postfix relay server?

For example, mailgun provides smtp credentials or api keys. The credentials can be used in application for authentication and send out emails.

Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Just use whatever Postfix supports, SMTP is certainly an option? I am not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: Configure Postfix to allow another VM to connect and send mail. https://serverfault.com/a/371696/437769 Note: port 25 is blocked in GCP, configure a different port number. The Postfix documentation explains how to configure Postfix.